# P/Invoke typedef struct to C#

Tags: c#, c, struct, pinvoke

I have created structs in C# based on what I have been given in C i believe. 
I'm still learning the ropes with P/Invoke but I didn't think this was too difficult. 
The first struct is a request struct.  The second struct is the response struct.
It does return information in the second struct but some of the values are "right" and some are "wrong".  So i'm thinking that it must be how I set up the struct in c#

I was hoping someone could do a review of my c# code to see if what I've done is correct. 
Thanks.

**Request Struct:**

```
typedef struct _tagGiftCardReqAdminCard
{
  char Password[9];
  char OperatorID[9];
  char Invoice[11];
  char CardNumber[80];
  char filler2[57];
  char FirstName[21];
  char filler3[126];
  long InitialBalance;
  char FinTrack2[40];
  char filler4[6];
  char ReferenceNumber[13];
  char filler5;
} TGiftCardReqAdminCard, *pTGiftCardReqAdminCard;
```

In C#

```
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack=1, CharSet=CharSet.Ansi)]
    public struct _tagGiftCardReqAdminCard
    {
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 9)]
        public string Password;

        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 9)]
        public string OperatorID;

        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 11)]
        public string Invoice;

        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 80)]
        public string CardNumber;

        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 57)]
        public string filler2;

        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 21)]
        public string FirstName;

        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 126)]
        public string filler3;

        public int InitialBalance;

        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 40)]
        public string FinTrack2;

        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 6)]
        public string filler4;

        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 13)]
        public string ReferenceNumber;

        public byte filler5;
    }
```

**Response Struct**

```
typedef struct _tagGiftCardRespAdminCard
{
  char Result;
  char TerminalId[17];
  char filler1[257];
  char Display[41];
  char Date[11];
  char Time[9];
  char RespCode[4];
  char InvNum[11];
  char filler2;
  char CustLang;
  char UserLang;
  char CardNum[20];
  char ExpDate[5];
  char ReferenceNumber[11];
  char RcptMsg[256];
  char filler3[353];
  long InitialBalance;
  char filler4[8];
  long LifeTimeBenefit;
  long RemainingBalance;
  char filler5[22];
  char MerchantNumber[17];
  char StoreNumber[17];
  char filler6[2];
  char BatchNum[14];
  char Password[9];
  char filler7[4];
  char OrigTransCode[6];
} TGiftCardRespAdminCard, *pTGiftCardRespAdminCard;
```

In C#

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
public struct _tagGiftCardRespAdminCard
{
    public byte Result;

    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 17)]
    public string TerminalId;

    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 257)]
    public string filler1;

    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 41)]
    public string Display;

    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 11)]
    public string Date;

    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 9)]
    public string Time;

    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 4)]
    public string RespCode;

    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 11)]
    public string InvNum;

    public byte filler2;

    public byte CustLang;

    public byte UserLang;

    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 20)]
    public string CardNum;

    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 5)]
    public string ExpDate;

    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 11)]
    public string ReferenceNumber;

    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 256)]
    public string RcptMsg;

    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 353)]
    public string filler3;

    public int InitialBalance;

    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 8)]
    public string filler4;

    public int LifeTimeBenefit;

    public int RemainingBalance;

    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 22)]
    public string filler5;

    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 17)]
    public string MerchantNumber;

    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 17)]
    public string StoreNumber;

    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 2)]
    public string filler6;

    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 14)]
    public string BatchNum;

    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 9)]
    public string Password;

    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 4)]
    public string filler7;

    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 6)]
    public string OrigTransCode;
}
```

Comment: Lovely.  What could possibly go wrong.

Comment: Are you 100% sure the first structure is strictly packed and there are no word/dword alignments on its char arrays?

Comment: Thanks Hans and Medinoc for taking a look.
The first structure is strictly packed. It'll return all 0's if not.
It's so frustrating when you don't get enough information. Also when I only have very limited experience with P/Invoke :)

Comment: You can check that all the numbers match. If you want some real help, how about telling us more about the failure. Where is the first "wrong" value? And perhaps proving to use that the structs really are packed.

Comment: And also show the function calls.